# Android Studio not stopping at any breakpoints

Tags: android-studio

My Android Studio is not stopping at breakpoints.

I read somewhere that setting minifyEnabled to false would help.

```
>      buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled true
>             proguardFile file('proguard-project.txt')
>             proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt')
>         }
>         debug {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFile file('proguard-project-debug.txt')
>             proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt')
>         }
>     }
```

Have you seen this?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Android studio halt at a break-point in debug mode only. Therefore you need to follow below steps

1. Add some break-point in code
2. Press Shift+f9 to run app in debug mode
3. It will encounter break-point when execution reach at first break-point